# Melee Range trigger collider does not detect object with Player tag

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

In my 2D game, I have a **Player** which has:

- a `BoxCollider2D` with `isTrigger=false`
- a dynamic `Rigidbody2D`
- a `Player` script

...tagged as *"Player"* and in the *"Player"* Layer.

Also I have an **Enemy** in the scene which has:

- a `BoxCollider2D` with `isTrigger=true`
- an *EnemyMelee* script

... tagged as *"Enemy"* and in the *"Enemy"* Layer.

The Enemy has its own collider because when to handle taking damage or changing colors when shot by the Player's bullets.

The Enemy has an empty child game object following it where it goes, called **MeleeRange** and it has:

- a `BoxCollider2D` with `isTrigger=true`
- a kinematic `Rigidbody2D`
- an `EnemyMeleeAttack` script

...tagged as *"MeleeRange"* and in the *"MeleeRange"* Layer.

What I want is: When Player is inside of the MeleeRange area, the `EnemyMeleeAttack` script will detect this and call the Coroutine from the `EnemyMelee` script.

I want my Enemy to trigger its "attackMove" animation and attack my Player every 1.5 seconds. It has an exit time to the idle animation, and because the Player is still in the MeleeRange collision area, the attack will start again and return to idle again.

**The problem is:** MeleeRange simply cannot see the Player tag in the area. I put Debug.Log if it detects the player but nothing happened.

`EnemyMeleeAttack` script:

```
public class EnemyMeleeAttack : MonoBehaviour {
    public EnemyMelee enemyMeleeScript;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if(coll.tag == "Player")
        {
        Debug.Log("MeleeRange Collision Reached!");
        enemyMeleeScript.anim.SetBool("isRunningBool", false);
        enemyMeleeScript.StartCoroutine(enemyMelee.attackStance());
        }
    }
}
```

`EnemyMelee` script:

```
public class EnemyMelee : Enemy {
    #region Variables
    public bool inRange;
    #endregion

    #region Attack
    public float attackTime;
    public float timeBetweenAttacks;
    #endregion

    #region Movement with AI
    public bool isRunningBool;
    public AIPath aipathScript;
    //public EnemyMeleeAttack emeleeattackScript;
    #endregion

    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        aipathScript = gameObject.GetComponent<AIPath>();
        aipathScript.OnTargetReached();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Code for if Enemy dies, disable all functions attached to Enemy.
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            GetComponent<AIPath>().enabled = false;
            StopCoroutine(attackStance());
        }

        DamageColorUpdate();

        //Reference from A*Pathfinding for following player and running animations when following occurs.
        if (aipathScript.reachedEndOfPath == false)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunningBool", true);
            inRange = false;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunningBool", false);
            inRange = true;
            //StartCoroutine(attackStance());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator attackStance()
    {
        if (Time.time >= attackTime)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunningBool", false);
            player.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(damage);
            attackTime = Time.time + timeBetweenAttacks;
            anim.SetTrigger("attackMove");

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `OnTriggerEnter2D`, not `OnTrigerEnter2D` in `EnemyMeleeAttack`?

Comment: On my script it is "Trigger" It probably happened like this while copying-pasting the script. I edited.